# Oracle Conditional sum

Tags: oracle, dml

This question was born in my mind looking at this kind of code:

```
select sum(value)
  into positive
  from my_table
 where value > 0;

 select sum(value)
  into negative
  from my_table
 where value < 0;
```

This works well for take the totals of this table.

But, my question is how I can get the sub-totals of `my_table` using only a statement.

### expected result:

Having this data on `my_table`

```
VALUE
-----
  1.0
 -2.0
  3.0
 -4.0
  5.0
 -6.7
  8.9
```

I'd a DML statement who can give me this output

```
positive | negative
---------+---------
    17.9 |    -12.7
```

Is this kind of operation possible?
If yes, how can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQL> r
  1  with t as (
  2      select  1.0 as x from dual
  3      union all select -2.0 as x from dual
  4      union all select  3.0 as x from dual
  5      union all select -4.0 as x from dual
  6      union all select  5.0 as x from dual
  7      union all select -6.7 as x from dual
  8      union all select  8.9 as x from dual)
  9  select sum(case when x > 0 then x else 0 end) as sum_of_positives,
 10         sum(case when x < 0 then x else 0 end) as sum_of_negatives
 11*   from t

SUM_OF_POSITIVES SUM_OF_NEGATIVES
---------------- ----------------
            17,9            -12,7
```

Comment: Hopefully Oracle one day supports the `filter` syntax: `select count(*) filter (where x > 0) as positive, count(*) filter (where x < 0) as negative from t;` This works in PostgreSQL 9.4+, if anyone is interested.

Comment: @colin'thart This page has a handy table about what dbs support `filter` functionality: [filter — Selective Aggregates](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter).