# Zero/NULL Case Trick

Tags: oracle, case, sum, terminology, oracle-19c

In the book *Getting Started with SQL*, Thomas Nield talks about a technique he calls the ***zero/null case trick***:

> There is a simple but powerful tool that can apply different filtering
> conditions to different aggregations. We can create separate total
> counts when a tornado was present versus not present in two separate
> columns:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, month,
> SUM(CASE WHEN tornado = 1 THEN precipitation ELSE 0 END) as tornado_precipitation,
> SUM(CASE WHEN tornado = 0 THEN precipitation ELSE 0 END) as non_tornado_precipitation
> FROM station_data
> WHERE year >= 1990
> GROUP BY year, month
> ```
>
> What we have effectively done is get rid of the WHERE conditions when
> tornado = 1 or tornado = 0, and then move those conditions to CASE
> expressions inside the SUM() functions. If the condition is met, the
> precipitation value is added to the sum. If not, a 0 is added, having
> no effect. We do these for both columns, on for when a tornado was
> present and one for when a tornado was not present respectively.
>
> You can make the CASE expression have as many condition/value pairs as
> you need, giving you the ability to do highly particular interceptions
> of values with your aggregations. You can also use this trick to
> emulate crosstabs and pivot tables, expressing aggregations into
> separate columns rather than in rows. A common example of this is
> doing current year/previous year analysis, as you can express separate
> years with different columns.

---

As a novice, that technique seems like it could come in really handy for summarizing data. I want to look up that technique online to get more information.

The author of that book calls the technique the "zero/null case trick". But when I google that term, I don't get many results.

Question:

Is there a generally accepted name for that technique? (that would yield more results when searching online)

Comment: Other handy functions you may want to investigate are NULLIF and COALESCE

Comment: Related: [O'Reilly - Conditionally Aggregating Data Using the Zero/NULL Case Trick](https://learning.oreilly.com/scenarios/sql-conditionally-aggregating/9781492083566/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is variously known as:

- [conditional sum](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98024/oracle-conditional-sum)
- [filtered aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/271903)
- [conditional aggregation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/269618)
- [selective aggregation](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter)

It may be either written explicitly using `CASE` or equivalently using `FILTER` syntax introduced with SQL:2003 e.g. `COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE tornado = 1)`. Currently Postgres, HSQLDB and SQLite support the new syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Excel (and possibly other spreadsheet software) calls this a "**pivot table**" because you take the row-based groups and essentially pivot them by 90 degrees when you put them into columns.

Since people are familiar with the term it carried over into the SQL world. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618323/create-a-pivot-table-with-postgresql/54858085#54858085)

Note that it is not necessarily the *best* way to do it, there might be other techniques like conditional aggregation (`FILTER`) and window functions available. (But I don't know anything about Oracle.)