# Query to filter only groupings having different values

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I need a simple query, but couldn't find the way to do it:

I have a table of services purchased by customers, where different customers may purchase the same service (trivially), and each customer may have several active or inactive services:

```
ServiceId  IsActive ServiceCustomerId
815        0        111
715        0        111
985        1        222
815        1        333
475        1        111
985        1        111
815        1        222
```

I want to get records of customers which have both active and inactive services, so the output would be (`ServiceId` can be omitted):

```
IsActive ServiceCustomerId
0        111
1        111
```

What I have is:

```
select ServiceCustomerId,IsActive from Services 
group by ServiceCustomerId, IsActive
having count(IsActive) > 1
order by ServiceCustomerId
```

Which gives:

```
IsActive ServiceCustomerId
0        111
1        111
1        222
```

[Demo can be seen here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff5904/10).

How do I filter only those having both `IsActive` groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select ServiceCustomerId, sum(case when IsActive=1 then 1 else 0 end) ActiveServices, count(*) TotalServices 
from TServices 
group by ServiceCustomerId
having sum(case when IsActive=1 then 1 else 0 end) between 1 and count(*)-1
order by ServiceCustomerId
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. You can use the demo I give [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff5904/10) - Please note that I added more rows to my example. I guess I was misunderstood about something, so please let me know where I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Clever! If you happen to know a way to still use the grouping set I had (`group by ServiceCustomerId, IsActive`) it would be great.

Comment: @HeyJude if you group on the `IsActive` field, it *uncollapses* the two related rows of the same customer such that they no longer are comparable and makes it more difficult to solve your problem (it would invalidate David's solution here). Without also selecting the `ServiceId` field, why would you care to see arbitrary `IsActive` values in your final results with no correlation to which service of that customer they belong to?

Comment: @J.D., I'm asking that because I think it would be valuable to know the count of records in each `(ServiceCustomerId, IsActive)` grouping, *of* those records (i.e. customers) which satisfies the requirement of having both `IsActive` 0 and 1.

Comment: @HeyJude Sounds good, you may want to add that to your original post for clarity.

Comment: That’s already there in the ActiveServices and TotalServices columns.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, that's true alright, but what if `IsActive` wasn't of `BIT` type but say of `INT` and could take multiple values (say, 5 different values)? I want to be able to see the division as in my second snippet. If you feel that's worth another question, I'll understand.

Comment: For future reference, it turns out this way of filtering has a name: [The Zero/NULL Case Trick](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299113/zero-null-case-trick). I've just used it to get records whose groups have zero rows of null values, [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/765d11/14).